# VBO Send email to CCK E-mail field

Tags: emails, views

I have a content type called "*Business*", and a user can have multiple "*Businesses*".

Each business has a "*business e-mail*" field. This is different from the users email address, and is different for every business.

I want to be able to use [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to send an email to all selected businesses. I have the view set up ok, and in the recipients field on the send email page I add the token....

```
[node:field-business-e-mail]
```

and I also tried...

```
[node:field_business_e_mail]
```

But I still get the error :

> Enter a valid email address or use a token e-mail address such as
>   `[node:author:mail]`.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I have refer to this [LINK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1066060). Hope you may get your solution.

Comment: Stick it as an answer and ill mark it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating code on `system.module` file. Below are the code :

```
   function system_send_email_action_validate($form, $form_state) {
       $form_values = $form_state['values'];
       $has_tokens = count(token_scan($form_values['recipient'])) > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
       if (!valid_email_address($form_values['recipient']) && !$has_tokens) {
          form_set_error('recipient', t('Enter a valid email address or use a token e-mail address such as %author.', array('%author' => '[node:author:mail]')));
       }
}
```

For any help, I have refer you to this [PATCH](https://www.drupal.org/node/1066060#pift-results-1066060).

This is not working directly try to do it manually.

Comment: This works perfectly, but unfortunately means hacking core. Do you know how i would override this in a custom module?